# Excel VBA Getexchangeuser.Getexchangeusermanager query

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

my main issue **how can i throw an activecellvalue to the getexchangeuser object to get that particular user's supervisor**? i am trying the code below as i am not sure how to do so but i'm getting an error 91 object variable not set.

```
Set Usersupervisor = myExchangeuser.GetExchangeUser(ActiveCell.Cells(1, 10)).GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
```

---

this code line though works if i need my OWN supervisor.

```
.To = outlookmail.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
```

---

basically i have the alias or username of the recipient which does resolve in outlook. i need to lookup that particular alias' manager information and use that in the .To field. is that even possible? most of the guides just doesn't fit my requirements.

```
Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myusername As String
Dim myExchangeuser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim mngname As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim mysupervisor As String

myusername = Environ("Username")

mysupervisor = CStr(myExchangeuser.GetExchangeUser(ActiveCell.Cells(1, 10)).GetExchangeUserManager.Alias)


Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application

Set outlookmail = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\" & myusername & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\x.oft")

With outlookmail



'.To = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 10)
'.To = outlookmail.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias
.To = mysupervisor

End With

ActiveCell.Cells(1, 13) = "Yes"
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 14) = DateTime.Now
outlookmail.Display
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i made it work. thanks to the numerous articles albeit not exact but useable to get the format of the syntax. thanks stack overflow:

```
Set olns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myrecipient = olns.CreateRecipient(PMstring)
myrecipient.Resolve
PMentry = myrecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.Alias



With outlookmail

.To = PMentry
```